# Is there simple way to create user defaults values for TextView in Android?

Tags: android, textview, default

I'm looking for simple way to create user defaults values for TextView in Android: I need the standart solution that user is seeing the previous value, that was entered by him to the TextView. Sure, there is way to store value of TextView at somewhere and then read it again while starting activity, but, may be, there is any simple tool to get what I wish ?

Comment: The word is 'standard', not 'standart'. A very common internet meme i guess :p. Sorry for the correction, but i can't have it that way :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store previous values and then get previous values from shared preferences to set as default values

Comment: Thanks for advice - I will try. I don't know why, but I was thinking that this way causes the appearence of dialog or activity with the list of SharedPreference - this is that I'd like to avoid, just previous value. thaks again.

Answer (score 1):

Just to get your question correctly:
You want to present the values the user selected/set in his last visit?

You can save those values in the SharedPreferences - That's what they're made for.
You can give the `google prediction api` a try.